# IE-9 giving fakepath when using input type file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I wasn't able to read the file in IE-9. I am generating base64 from the url. In all the other browsers it works, except for IE-9. Can anyone please help me with this?
 I am getting c://fakepath/images.jpg in IE-9

```
if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) ||  !!document.documentMode == true )) //IF IE > 10
      {
      tmppath = $("#hi").val();
      console.log("only in ie"+tmppath);
      }
else{
    var selectedFile = this.files[0];
tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
console.log("temp path other"+tmppath);
}

console.log("temp path"+tmppath);
<input name="hello1" type="file" id="hi" accept="image/*"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have code explicitly branching for IE9 and earlier and reading the `value` of the `input`. The `value` of a `type="file"` `input` *always* has a fake path (on all browsers), because you are not allowed to know the actual path of the file.

The other branch makes use of `createObjectURL`, which isn't supported by IE9. (IE9 doesn't suport the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) at all.)

You'll have to submit a form containing the file input, and deal with the file server-side.